# Retrieve Textbox value in asp.net ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I generating a listview (a list of products for user to make order) with a textbox inside. User may enter quantity of product that want to order in this textbox. I set the initial value of this textbox to 0. My issue is when user insert a new quantity value in this textbox and click submit button, it should retrieve the value that user insert, but it still retrieve the initial value which is 0. Below is my code, can anyone tell me which part of my code is incorrect?

HTML page

```
<div class="row">


        <asp:Listview runat="server" ID="Listview1">

            <ItemTemplate>                    
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" id="divRow">                                  
                <div class="wrap-listview-block">

                    <div class="listview-block-inner">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                                <%--<img src="../images/img-product-gerbang-jingga.jpg">--%>
                                <telerik:RadBinaryImage runat="server" ID="RadBinaryImage1" DataValue='<%#Eval("ProductImg") %>' Width="80.02" Height="109.55"
                                                            AutoAdjustImageControlSize="false" ToolTip='<%#Eval("ProdCode", "Photo of {0}") %>'
                                                            AlternateText='<%#Eval("ProdCode", "Photo of {0}") %>' />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 listing-right">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>(<%#Eval("ProdCode")%>) <%#Eval("ProdName")%> </h3>




                                    <div class="btn-details">
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalInfo"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPromo"><i class="fa fa-gift" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBrochure"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRecipe"><i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="btn-details">

                                        <form class="form-inline">

                                            <%--<select class="form-control input-sm col-xs-6">
                                                <option>Carton</option>
                                                <option>Piece</option>
                                            </select>--%>

                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuantity" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-sm col-xs-6">
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="1" Selected="True">Carton</asp:ListItem>
                                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Piece</asp:ListItem> 
                                            </asp:DropDownList>

                                            <div class="input-group col-xs-6">


                                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-sub" ID="btnDown"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>

                                                </span>
                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="form-control input-sm text-right" Text="0"  Width="90"></asp:TextBox>

                                                <span class="input-group-btn">

                                                   <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-sm btn-sub" ID="btnUp"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </span>



                                                <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" Runat="server" TargetControlID="txtQuantity" TargetButtonDownID="btnDown" TargetButtonUpID="btnUp"/>

                                            </div>

                                        </form> 

                                    </div>                                          

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- listing block -->                                

            </div><!--Product block -->                
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Listview>




    </div>

    <div class="footer-bar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <asp:LinkButton  runat="server" ID="btnProceedOrder" OnClick="btnProceedOrder_Click" >
                    <div class="footer-inner">                          
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart' aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litProceedOrder" Text="<%$ Resources:Lang, ProceedOrder %>"></asp:Literal>
                    </div>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String UserName = Utils.Session.Get(Constants.SessionObjects.UserName);

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = this.GetData();

        Listview1.DataSource = dt;

        Listview1.DataBind();

    }
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    string RetailLink = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultDB"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(RetailLink))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_mProduct_Sel_ByPrincipalRetailer#PWA " + UserName + ", " + PricipalID.ToInt32()))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


protected void btnProceedOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ListViewDataItem row in Listview1.Items)
    {

        TextBox txtQuantity = row.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox;

        string Quantity = txtQuantity.Text.ToString(); //string Quantity keep getting "0", I need to get the value that user insert.


    }
}
```

Comment: Where you initiate `quantity` text box to zero ? it may occurred because of `PostBack`

Comment: Try using `IsPostBack` checking on `Page_Load` event to see if the binding works (`if (!IsPostBack) { // data binding }`).

Comment: Hi Tetsuya, I already do my data binding in (if (!Postback)), but it still get my old value zero.

Comment: Hi Aria, I initiate right here >> <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="form-control input-sm text-right" Text="0"  Width="90"></asp:TextBox>, but the problem is already do my data binding in (if (!Postback)).